# Is it a good practice to build autosizing elements depending on the screen dimensions for a mobile Web App?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm developing a Mobile App through Cordova. Should I better use media query css properties or is it possible and maintainable to size the HTML elements, fonts, images depending of the size of the user screen ?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not suitable for this site; sorry. You'll get answers both ways, and none will be the "correct" answer, and that is frowned upon.

Comment: That said, my gut feeling is that it's not a good idea to have font sizes in vw, since screen sizes vary wildly, even between mobile devices.